# jQuery: How to use modifier keys on form submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, forms

Say I have a form that looks like this:

> `[ Animal name input field ]` <kbd>Add button</kbd>

If I type a name and hit enter, an animal with the given name is added to a table. Works fine. What I would like now is to call the current way of working "quick add" and add a new feature called "slow add", which I am not quite sure how to do. Basically what I want is that if for example the shift key is held down when enter or the button is clicked, I want the form submit method to do something slightly different. In my case I want it to open up a form where more details on the animal can be added before it is added to the table.

Problem is I'm not quite sure how to do this. I have tried add a FireBug `console.info(eventData)` in my current submit function and I have found that the `eventData` contains an altKey, shiftKey and controlKey property, but they are always undefined even when I hold those keys down.

So, does anyone know how I can do something special in my submit handler when certain modifier keys were pressed when the form was submitted?

---

**Temporary solution**

Ended up ignoring the submit-button-shift-click-feature and instead just have the quick add feature as shift-enter-in-input-fields. Implemented it something like this:

```
$('#new-task')
    .submit(onNewAnimal)
    .keypress(onNewAnimal);


function onNewAnimal(event)
{
    if(event.type == 'keypress' && event.which != 13)
        return true;

    if(event.shiftKey)
    {
        // Quick add
    }
    else
    {
        // Open slow add dialog
    }

    return false;
}
```

Still curious if there is a better way, but until then, this is what I have. Maybe it can help someone else as well :)

Comment: here is a simular question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847135/check-ctrl-shift-alt-keys-on-click-event

Comment: @John: That question is asking about differing between left and right versions of the modifier keys. Also it talks about the click event and not the submit event.

Answer (score 2):

You may get shift pressed by $(document).keyup and $(document).keydown events. For example my code for control key is

```
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 17) $.isCtrl=false;
}).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 17) $.isCtrl=true;
});
```

And just check

```
if ($.isCtrl) { ... }
```

in your handler

Comment: Wouldn't that fail if the user released the control key before the form was submitted? Of course it would probably go faster than that, but technically speaking. And also, you say the code for your control key is 17. Does that mean that this code potentially would only work with your keyboard?

Comment: Cause of handler keyup it is not fail if user release key before submit. $.isCtrl will be false. What about key code it may differs in different browsers and operating systems. I know about control: Firefox in Windows and Chrome in Mac OS have different codes. You should test it on different situations

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the modifier keys aren't sent with form submits or input buttons, but they are sent on other 'click's, including input[type=image]'s.  So, re-create your form using a input[type=image] where your 'Add Button' is now.  You could also just use a styled A-element if you wish.  The benefit here is that you can pretty much make it look just like a button and not have to rely on images.

Combine this with the keypress solution you posed in your question and you should get the whole thing you're after.

Working demo here:
http://jsfiddle.net/mkoistinen/afPHh/

Answer (score -2):

There is easier way. 
On every keydown you have built in event variable:

    `{
originalEvent: [object KeyboardEvent],
type: keydown,
timeStamp: 1277147610854,
jQuery1277147575359: true,
which: 65,
wheelDelta: undefined,
view: [object DOMWindow],
toElement: undefined,
target: ,
srcElement: ,
shiftKey: false,
screenY: undefined,
screenX: undefined,
relatedTarget: undefined,
relatedNode: undefined,
prevValue: undefined,
pageY: 0,
pageX: 0,
originalTarget: undefined,
offsetY: undefined,
offsetX: undefined,
newValue: undefined,
metaKey: false,
layerY: 0,
layerX: 0,
keyCode: 65,
handler: function (event) {
  if (event.keyCode == '13') {
     event.preventDefault();
   }
   xTriggered++;
   var msg = 'Handler for .keydown() called ' + xTriggered + ' time(s).';
  $.print(msg, 'html');
  $.print(event);
},
fromElement: undefined,
eventPhase: 2,
detail: 0,
data: undefined,
currentTarget: ,
ctrlKey: false,
clientY: undefined,
clientX: undefined,
charCode: 0,
cancelable: true,
button: undefined,
bubbles: true,
attrName: undefined,
attrChange: undefined,
altKey: false,
handleObj: [object Object],
preventDefault: function (){this.isDefaultPrevented=Z;var a=this.originalEvent;if(a){a.preventDefault&&a.preventDefault();a.returnValue=false}},
stopPropagation: function (){this.isPropagationStopped=Z;var a=this.originalEvent;if(a){a.stopPropagation&&a.stopPropagation();a.cancelBubble=true}},
stopImmediatePropagation: function (){this.isImmediatePropagationStopped=Z;this.stopPropagation()},
isDefaultPrevented: function Y(){return false},
isPropagationStopped: function Y(){return false},
isImmediatePropagationStopped: function Y(){return false}
}`

**altKey: false,**
AND:
**ctrlKey: false,**

Comment: On keydown yes, but not on other events like the form submit event. There they are `undefined`.