# How to perform action on keypress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, onkeydown

My code works perfect if I want to perform an action when pressing the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key...

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if(e.ctrlKey){
        if($('.selected').parent().next().length == 0){
            switchTabs($('.selected').parent().parent().find('a:first'));
            return false;
         }else{
            switchTabs($('.selected').parent().next().children('a'));
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

However I only want this code to activate when I press only the right control button...

```
if(e.rightctrlkey)
```

doesn't work... if there is a correct method, what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to do this in general. You can do it in IE only:

```
// Assuming you have a key event stored in variable 'e':
if (e.ctrlLeft) {
    alert("Left!");
} else if (e.ctrlRight) {
    alert("Right!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `event.keyLocation` attribute, Left=0, Right=1. Look over [here](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html) for details.

Also look over in this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847135/check-ctrl-shift-alt-keys-on-click-event).

Comment: Not that helpful: `keyLocation` does not appear to be correctly supported in any current browser.