# jQuery: How to catch keydown + mouse click event?

Tags: keypress, keydown, jquery

I have a `div` element. I need to catch a mouse click on this `div` while alt-key (keyCode = 17) is pressed.

Here is what i've got to catch key press:

```
// Html
<div id="targetDiv">I want to put a ding in the universe.</div>
```

```
// Java-script
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).bind('keydown', function(event){
        if ( 17 == event.keyCode ) {
           // How to catch mouse click on $('#targetDiv') ?
        }
    });
});
```

How to catch mouse click on div while alt-key is pressed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check Ctrl / Shift / Alt keys on 'click' event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847135/check-ctrl-shift-alt-keys-on-click-event) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445613/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781142/

Comment: Good question.  I wonder about race conditions with code vs user in some possible posted solutions though.

Comment: Mark: Javascript is inherently single-threaded, so race conditions become a non-issue.

Comment: It's interesting to note that this won't work for me under X11 (i.e. Linux) because Alt+click is used by the window manager to move windows.  There's nothing wrong with the code (e.g. Nick Craver's solution), but the functionality is inherently broken for X11 users.

Comment: @Milan - That's not *entirely* true in some cases, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734025/is-javascript-guaranteed-to-be-single-threaded

Comment: @Nick - Thanks for the link.... learn something new every day...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can check the [`.altKey` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.altKey), for example:

```
$(function() {
  $("#targetDiv").click(function(event) {
    if (event.altKey) {
       //do something, alt was down when clicked
    }
  });
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Du7rQ/).

Comment: Nice solution to listen to click event first. Thanks.

Comment: it's for Alt. For Ctrl use event.ctrlKey