# JQuery: Simulate Key event on on Mouse Click

Tags: jquery

I want to create a Link that, if you click on it, calls a simulates a Key combination like `CTRL`+`/` or `CRTL`+`-`.

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to look here for a similar effect:
[jQuery: How to catch keydown + mouse click event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872498/jquery-how-to-catch-keydown-mouse-click-event)

However, if you are meaning that a user is to press:

`Ctrl`, `/`, and `click` at the same time, that may be more difficult. You also should consider if there is a simpler key combination for you to choose for the user's sake.

**Edit:**

I think I may have misunderstood what you are looking for, can you clean up the wording of your question?

I now think that you are meaning to simulate the keypress when a user clicks the link. If you are intending to use this to change the "zoom" or the text size on the page (ie: larger / smaller buttons), you should consider using em for text-sizes and then changing the top level font-size with css on the click.

This would allow you to provide the same functionality, but isn't a hackish way to get there.

**Edit 2:**

Here's what you're looking for: [Simulate Keypress With jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468384/simulate-keypress-with-jquery)

Comment: i need to call a key press with click on a link. Shortcut CTRL++ must be callen with a click on a link, or a similar function.