# How to stick div to the top of parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sticky

What I'm trying to do is,

- always stick `class="new"` div to the top of `.inside` div when you
  scroll down.
- When you click on new div, create new row inside (at the top of
  table not at the bottom like now)

http://jsfiddle.net/tt13/5CxPr/13/

Answer (score 4):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/5CxPr/18/) is a fiddle of what you want to achieve. Use `prependTo` instead of `appendTo` and use `position:absolute;top:0;` for keeping it on the top

Comment: thx for fast reply. One more thing, What I want to do is, to select mutiple rows by pressiong ctrl+left-click and one and only selection with only one - left click (I mean remove previous selected and select last clicked one; just like windows icon selection). How can I modify current code?

Comment: @epic_syntax you sould post that as a different question then

Comment: @epic_syntax Do not post comments on all the answers and ask another question as a thread, post it as another question.

Anyhow, look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847135/check-ctrl-shift-alt-keys-on-click-event

Also `live()` method is deprecated, use `on()` instead. http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 1):

use `prependTo()` instead of `appendTo()` http://jsfiddle.net/uday99/5CxPr/20/

Comment: thx for fast reply. One more thing, What I want to do is, to select mutiple rows by pressiong ctrl+left-click and one and only selection with only one - left click (I mean remove previous selected and select last clicked one; just like windows icon selection). How can I modify current code?

Answer (score 1):

[try this one instead](http://jsfiddle.net/5CxPr/17/)

the code is too long to put here but here are key notes:

- to append to the top, use `.prependTo()`
- separate the new button and create a scrollable div below it

Comment: thx for fast reply. One more thing, What I want to do is, to select mutiple rows by pressiong ctrl+left-click and one and only selection with only one - left click (I mean remove previous selected and select last clicked one; just like windows icon selection). How can I modify current code?