# How to transform a "click" on a "ctrl + click" on javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need, when I click in a multiple select list option to transform a mouse "click" in a "ctrl + click" to select multiple itens.

Now I'm doing this:

```
$(document).on("mousedown", '.CentroCusto_new option', function (e) {
    this.selected = !this.selected;
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

But this code didn't work on Internet Explorer because IE can't 'find' the selector 'option'.

Then I want to try to do this in another way and I need to know how to simulate ctrl + click when I click.

Comment: Which IE? and aslo possible duplicate of [Check Ctrl / Shift / Alt keys on 'click' event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847135/check-ctrl-shift-alt-keys-on-click-event)

Answer (score 0):

If ctrl is clicked the event.ctrlKey is true (in your case e.ctrlKey;)

```
$(document).on("mousedown", function (e) {
    console.log(e.ctrlKey); // it's boolean
});
```

Comment: Should be keydown rather than keypress. Also, not all keys trigger keypress events in all browsers.

Comment: yeah... was thinking keydown... typed keypress :) My bad.

It worked for me. ;)
Maybe there is an info in EVENT data of event? :D
function(event) {} <--- this event ;)

Googled a bit ;D TRY THIS: event.ctrlKey

Comment: Information on events in javascript can be found on http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events_examples.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp