# Detect special character produced by combination of shift key and some other key

Tags: javascript, html

For instance, how can I detect the `@` character(using `keyup`, `keypress`) which is produced when I use `shift` + `2` keys simultaneously?

I tried using `which` to detect if both `shift` and `2` were entered one after the other but how can I detect if `shift` was kept pressed and *then* `2` was pressed?

**Note:** I don't just want to detect if the `shift` and `2` keys are pressed one after the other, *but* if `shift` *and* `2` keys were pressed at the same time to generate `@`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check Ctrl / Shift / Alt keys on 'click' event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847135/check-ctrl-shift-alt-keys-on-click-event)

Comment: The keypress event should give you the code for the @ character. If not, just check for the 2 key's keycode and the .shiftKey property.

Comment: No, it gives me the code for '2' and 'shift' keys but not '@'.

Comment: @Andrey - the linked question isn't a duplicate because it is about mouse click plus shift/ctrl.

Comment: @nnnnnn, as you say, but still, answer from there is applicable here. Totally same principe

Comment: to put @nnnnnn's comment and the answer together - `e.which==50&&e.shiftKey`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced this problem and I got solution is like:
Keycode is just detecting which key is pressed..May b not which is another character on that

```js
$.ctrl = function(key, callback, args) {
  $(document).bind('keydown', function(e) {
    if (!args) args = []; // IE barks when args is null
    if (e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == key.charCodeAt(0)) {
      e.preventDefault();
      callback.apply(this, args);
      return false;
    }
  });
}
$.ctrl('2', function() {
  alert('@');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Summarizing the answer here as mentioned by JNF: (e.shiftKey && e.which === 50) will return true if shift and 2 are pressed.